# Finding a repeated element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have come up with this problem on my own. I am only a beginner and learning C++ currently.
Q. Find all the repeated elements in an array and provide their index number.

I am trying to solve this question using for loops.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void arfn(int var1[],int length){
    int x,y;
    int store[length];
    for(x=0;x<length;x++){
        store[x]=var1[x];}

    for(int counter=0;counter<length;counter++)
    {
        cout<<store[counter]<<endl;
        for(x=0;x<length;x++) {
           for (y=0;y!=x && y<length;y++)
            /*By these loops i expect to find index number of repeated elements, 
                eliminating the case of program showing the same index numbers*/
            {   
                if(store[x]=store[y]) {
                    cout<<store[x]<<" "<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<endl;
                } 
            }
        }            
    }

}
int main()
{
    int numbers[]={22,33,44,55,55};
    int length=5;
    arfn(numbers,length);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to find the output as
`55 3 4`
but the output is really huge and is nowhere close to the desired output.

Comment: `if(store[x]=store[y])` --> `if(store[x] == store[y])`

Comment: OT: you may also want to look if you can do it with only 2 loops, its definitely possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest, that you get acquainted with the STL first, if you are willing to make C++ a power tool for you.

The following program does the job by transforming a vector to a map, which takes care of the indices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

void printDuplicates(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
    for (auto iter=arr.begin(); iter!=arr.end(); iter++)
    {
        auto index = std::distance(arr.begin(), iter);
            map[*iter].push_back(index);
    }
    for (auto& iter : map)
    {
        if (map[iter.first].size()>1)
        {       

            std::cout << iter.first << " ";
            for (auto iterIndices : map[iter.first])
            {
                std::cout << iterIndices << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr{ 1,2,5,7,2,8,4,7 };
    printDuplicates(arr);

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try to learn it after I get acquainted with basics of C++

Comment: I would highly recommend `https://www.codewars.com/` to learn a new programming language. It has the learning by example approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many articles on this algorithmic problem 
here is one:
[Solving Algorithmic Problems: Find a Duplicate in an Array](https://medium.com/solvingalgo/solving-algorithmic-problems-find-a-duplicate-in-an-array-3d9edad5ad41)

You should approach this challenge with some questions

1. What is the expected input size?
2. What is the required complexity?
3. Can I use more memory to optimize the complexity?
4. Is my input sorted or not?

Then you may start with the naive implementation and try to figure 
how can it be optimized

For example:
Which parts of my code run more than once

As for using C++, try looking for C++ specifics,
use std::vector or std::array instead of C style arrays
look for STL algorithms which may solve some of your questions